# What is the scope of import files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example I have 2 files

main.py and functions.py

main.py needed some functions from functions.py
Both main.py and functions.py needed the module socket.

if the file are written in such as

```
import socket
from functions import *
#code here
```

do I still need to add the import socket in functions.py?
or can all the files that is added can access the module as long as the page importing it has imported the module before the adding?

Comment: And star imports are generally discouraged

Answer (score 0):

All the files that is added can access the module. But keep in mind that if you are trying to import another function you have to specify their variables.

Comment: it is easy to check that this is not true